# ¿Cómo encontrar los posibles sucedáneos del espacio en blanco para limpiar/reemplazar contenido correctamente?

Tags: html, caracteres

Estoy trabajando con un contenido de texto que obtuve de un documento Word y que estoy pasando a HTML, haciendo reemplazos, quitando los dobles o más espacios en blanco seguidos, etc.

Pero el contenido tiene una especie de sucedáneo del espacio en blanco que me evade ciertas operaciones.

Para poner un ejemplo, aquí:

> `<p>R. Muchos dicen: ¿Quién nos hará ver la dicha? * Haz brillar sobre nosotros, Señor, la luz de tu rostro.</p> <p>V. Traed a la memoria los días pasados, en que después de ser iluminados, debisteis soportar un duro y doloroso combate.</p>`

Yo necesito reemplazar el `[espacio] * [espacio]` por este carácter: `|`, de modo que quede así:

> `<p>R. Muchos dicen: ¿Quién nos hará ver la dicha?|Haz brillar sobre nosotros, Señor, la luz de tu rostro.</p> <p>V. Traed a la memoria los días pasados, en que después de ser iluminados, debisteis soportar un duro y doloroso combate.</p>`

La búsqueda/reemplazo que hago me falla en algunos casos, porque existe una especie de sucedáneo del espacio en blanco representada por un símbolo paracido a <sub>`^`</sub> cuando muestro los carácteres invisibles.

Aquí se puede ver, en la parte en azul, en vez de haber dos puntitos rojos (que representan un espacio en blanco), hay a cada lado del asterisco un símbolo como <sub>`^`</sub>. Ese símbolo es imperceptible para la visibilidad del documento, pero no es un espacio en sí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es si puedo encontrar en alguna parte esos sucedáneos del espacio en blanco, los cuales **no son espacios en blanco, pero funcionan como tal, porque no se muestran en el texto visible**.

La idea es tener un array de esos valores para crear una función de limpieza que me los sustituya todos por espacios en blanco reales y evitar así el problema que estoy teniendo.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el valor de ese caracter? He probado a copiar de tu pregunta y hacer `"? * H".charCodeAt(1)`y devuelve 32 (espacio *normal*), con lo que no puedo reproducir el problema.

Comment: @PabloLozano, en la pregunta he puesto el carácter, el cual es este: -->` ``
<-ahí está, no sé si se verá... (tuve que poner dos identificadores al final), debería estar en medio de los dos identificadores, ignorando el último. [Verificándolo aquí](http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html) obtengo el código `160`, parece que es el equivalente HTML de `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 2):

Parece que ese carácter es el [*espacio duro*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_duro).

No sé qué herramienta usas para hacer las sustituciones, pero Notepad++ o Visual Studio Code, además de casi cualquier IDE, te debería permitir buscar y reemplazar por espacios usando una expresión regular. Y el caracter especial `\s` representa cualquier espacio, incluido el que te preocupa, retornos de carro, tabulaciones...:

En [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> **\s** :   Coincide con un carácter de espacio, entre ellos incluidos espacio, tab, salto de página, salto de linea y retorno de carro. Equivalente a `[\f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​​\u202f\u205f​\u3000]`.

```js
const label=document.getElementById('l');
let t=label.innerText;
console.log(t);
console.log('Primer espacio:',t.charCodeAt(4));
t=t.replace(/\s+/,' '); //reemplazamos cualquier cantidad de espacios por uno
console.log('Resultado',t)
console.log('Primer espacio:',t.charCodeAt(4));
```

```html
<label id="l">Hola&nbsp; qué tal<label>
```

Comment: Pablo yo uso `Coda` como IDE. No había pensado en usar REGEX, lo cuál sería una buena opción como dices. Yo estaba simplemente buscando los espacios normales.